# Como guardar desde un form de angular a un servidor nodejs una imagen

Tags: nodejs, angular, aplicación-web

estoy haciendo una pagina web con angular y **nodejs**, quiero que los trabajadores que se registren tengan la opcion de guardar una foto de perfil, entonces tengo un formulario de **angular (ngForm)** y tal y le he metido un input file para la subida de imagen, hasta ahi bien.

**Por la parte del frontend**

```
<style>
  mat-form-field {
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  #botonera a {
    margin: 8px;
  }
</style>


<div class="col-lg-12">
  <h2 style="text-align: center">Creacion de empleado</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12" style=" text-align: center">


  <form #formulario="ngForm" action="" (ngSubmit)="insertarEmpleado()" ngForm>
    <div class="example-container">

      <mat-form-field hintLabel="">
        <input matInput #input maxlength="9" placeholder="DNI" pattern="(([X-Z]{1})([-]?)(\d{7})([-]?)([A-Z]{1}))|((\d{8})([-]?)([A-Z]{1}))"
          [(ngModel)]="empleado_nuevo.dni" name="dni">
      </mat-form-field>


      <!-- [ngModel]="empleado_nuevo.nombre" -->
      <mat-form-field hintLabel="">
        <input matInput #input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" [(ngModel)]="empleado_nuevo.nombre" name="nombre">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field hintLabel="">
        <input matInput #input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s\-]+" [(ngModel)]="empleado_nuevo.apellidos"
          name="apellidos">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field hintLabel="">
        <input matInput #input type="text" placeholder="Departamento" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" [(ngModel)]="empleado_nuevo.departamento"
          name="departamento">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field hintLabel="">
        <input matInput #input type="number" min="0" placeholder="Sueldo" [(ngModel)]="empleado_nuevo.sueldo" name="sueldo">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field hintLabel="">
        <input matInput #input type="date" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" [(ngModel)]="empleado_nuevo.fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento">
      </mat-form-field>

      <div style="text-align: center" class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="file" placeholder="Imagen de perfil" [(ngModel)]="empleado_nuevo.imagen_perfil" name="imagen_perfil" style="margin:0 auto; width: 300px;margin-bottom: 45px;">
      </div>



      <!--======-->


      <div id="botonera">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="insertarEmpleado()">Enviar</button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="limpiarFormulario(formulario)">Limpiar</button>
      </div>




    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Por la parte del **backend** tengo lo siguiente :

el schema que esto intentando hacer es el siguiente , que no acaba de compilar bien:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema,File} = mongoose;


const empleado_schema = new Schema({
    dni:{type:String,required:true, unique:true},
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    apellidos:{type:String, required:true},
    departamento:{type:String, required:true},
    sueldo:{type:String, required:true},
    fecha_nacimiento:{type:Date, required:true},
    imagen_perfil:{type:File,required:true}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('tbEmpleadosss',empleado_schema);
```

como se puede apreciar ahi lo que intento es que la imagen que suba el empleado al registrarse en el formulario quede guardada en nodejs para cuando vaya a su perfil salga su imagen, pero ese es otrro tema por ahora quiero poder guardarla.

- ¿Es correcto tener el schema definido de essa manera, es decir , con el campo imagen tipo file o deberia ser de tipo string para que solo guarde la direccion de donde se guardo y mediante programacion en tiempo de ejecucion en si de la app lo cargue?

  - ¿Como podria hacerlo de forma correcta el tema de subir fichero, me imagino que tendria que crear dentro de la app una arpeta llamada imagenes donde suba todas las imagenes?
  - ¿Y si quiero que cada trabajador tenga una foto de perfil y un numero indeterminado de fotos como una especie de galeria , tendria que hacer un array de direcciones en el schema?

Comment: Si estás usando ficheros en una carpeta entonces `image_perfil` debe ser un string apuntando al path. Si estás usando MongoDb para almacenarlos entonces debe ser un ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede utilizar string o file, yo uso string, y va bien, pero no es la verdad absoluta.
Si usas string, debes crear una carpeta donde se suban las imágenes, y en la bd tendrás el nombre de la foto y la extensión : ejm 'user.jpg'; 
Y para la galería yo lo haría de esta forma.
Crearía otra colección, que se relacione con el usuario, para la galería o incluirlo en la colección de los datos del usuario, pero que no sea la que use para el login

```
  image:

            [  
                {
                    url:{String },


                 },

            ],
    user :{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
```